# If $T$ is quasinilpotent operator, then $‎‎\parallel‎ T^n ‎‎\parallel‎^{\frac{1}{n}}‎\rightarrow‎ 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Can someone prove that if $T$ is quasinilpotent operator, then $‎‎\parallel‎ T^n ‎‎\parallel‎^{\frac{1}{n}}‎\rightarrow‎ 0$, where $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the spectral radius?

Comment: You mean $\rho (A)=\lim _n ‎‎\parallel‎ A^n ‎‎\parallel‎^{\frac{1}{n}}‎$?

Comment: Yes. If you can use that, it's immediate.